# SharePoint 2010 Custom pages with custom relational SQL database -

Tags: sharepoint

The main/default page of the SP application has 3 buttons and clicking any of the buttons will open an empty form. Right now the link to the form is broken. Also, all the existing records will not open because the link to the form is broken.
This is the error:
An unexpected error has occurred.
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: 12bd11a1-818a-c061-014d-0d0441daf92e